# Javascript console not printing called function

Tags: javascript

I just started learning JavaScript and I am trying to improve a "Rock, Scissors, Paper" game I built(see code below).

I try to build the game without the last function, input(). But I learnt that I can only use "return" in a function. When I print the function using console.log() it worked without the input() function.

I want to learn how I can do this making use of the input() function and as well as be able to call the gamePlay() inside the input(). Any help will be appreciated.

```
var gamePlay = function (userGameChoice) {
    var computerChoice = Math.random(0, 1);
    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    } else {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    }
    var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
        if (choice1 === choice2) {
            return "The result is a tie!";
        }
        if (choice1 === "rock") {
            if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                return "rock wins";
            } else {
                return "paper wins";
            }
        }
        if (choice1 === "paper") {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
                return "paper wins";
            } else {
                return "scissors wins";
            }
        }
        if (choice1 === "scissors") {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
                return " rock wins";
            } else {
                return "scissors wins"
            }
        }
    }

    compare(userGameChoice, computerChoice);

}

var input = function (userChoice) {
    if (userChoice === "rock") {
        return gamePlay("rock");
    } else if (userChoice === "paper") {
        return gamePlay("paper");
    } else if (userChoice === "scissors") {
        return gamePlay("scissors");
    } else {
        return "Invalid input";
    }
}
input(prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?"));
```

Comment: Note that while `Math.random(0, 1)` will work (at least in some browsers), it technically does not accept any arguments, will ignore the arguments passed, and always pass a random value from 0 (inclusive) to 1 (exclusive).

Comment: Here is a good implementation if you want something to compare to: http://jsbin.com/AfokISAx/3/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `gamePlay` function does not return a value. It calls `compare` which does return a value but because `gamePlay` doesn't have a return statement it actually return `undefined`.

If you were to `console.log(gamePlay("rock"));` you would see `undefined`.

Side notes: also the input function could use a switch statement instead of if/then/elses.

Comment: making  `gamePlay` to return `compare` solves the problem. Wrote the script with the limited knowledge I just acquired that why I couldn't use the other identified methods . Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
var options    = ["rock", "scissors", "paper"];
var userinput  = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var gameResult = "Invalid Input";

if (options.indexOf(userinput) > -1) {
    gameResult = gamePlay(userinput);
}

alert(gameResult);
```

This takes the user input and compares it to a list of valid options. If it exists (`>-1`) then it will run the `gamePlay` method, storing the result in the variable `gameResult`

Comment: re-assigning a function like this kind of obfuscates the code readability. Although clever and useful it would make learning the code a bit more difficult than usual.

Comment: @Sukima I think I misread the question, I thought the OP was trying to not use the Input method. +1 to your answer, I didn't see the missing `return` statement on the `gamePlay` method